# Azure load balancer on Kubernetes not loading endpoint

Tags: azure, kubernetes, load-balancing

My service has a load balancer. I can run up the service and it will show that it successfully created the load balancer as well as the service looking healthy.

I have a website running inside the service so i want to be able to access the site using externalIP:port.

Every time i go to the site (externalIP:port) it just keeps loading and doesn't redirect me to the site.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

**Update:**
The problems was the with the `labels`. The endpoints were live but they were not pointing to the right deployment I had, so it would not know where to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the problem.

The problems was the with the `labels`. The endpoints were live but they were not pointing to the right deployment I had, so it would not know where to go.

I added the `name` label and referred to it in the `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

does your loadbalancer have an ingress to go with it? usually you'll need
1. ingress controller
2. ingress.yaml
3. deployment.yaml
4. service.yaml

if you only have a lb and service, it wont present anything.

Comment: I don't have an ingress. Current "stack" is Service, Deployment; with LB on the Service and Volumes mounted on the deployed pods. Do I have to use an Ingress? Also is there any chance that the service will auto-create a ingress if not explicitly created. I ask this because it has worked with this set up before, but only twice.

Comment: found the solution - see answer posted.